# ActionScript 3 goto and play event not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

I have a navigation and inside the navigation movie clip, I have buttons and I put this code in my of my button frames

```
aboutbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goAbout);
function goAbout(e:MouseEvent){
    this.gotoAndPlay('245');
}
```

But this didnt work and when I click my button it does nothing, is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.gotoAndPlay('245');
```

`'245'` is a string and `gotoAndPlay` interprets as a frame label. Remove the quotes, passing an integer, to go to the frame 245.

```
aboutbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goAbout);
function goAbout(e:MouseEvent){
    this.gotoAndPlay(245);
}
```

If that still doesn't work, make sure `this` refers to the movieclip you want to change the frame. For example, if this code is in the document class, referring to the root instance, this will change the stage's frame.

If you want to change the button frame (only makes sense if it's a `SimpleButton` instance), change `this` to `aboutbtn`, for example.

If it's anything else, you'll to give us more context, it could be a load of other things (different stage? is there a frame 245? is the button mouse enabled? is there any invisible buttons on top of the object?).

Edit:

After clarification: if you want to change the frame of the object *above* `nav`, its parent, use:

```
aboutbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goAbout);
function goAbout(e:MouseEvent){
    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(245);
}
```

Comment: That did not work, when I click on the button it still does nothing.

Comment: Added a few other possibilities. Try experimenting with it, replacing the `gotoAndPlay` code with something else to make sure it's working, for example.

Comment: bacially I have new at flash. I have Scene 1, I have a movie clip called nav and inside the movie clip I have a button called aboutbtn, when someone clicks the aboutbtn, I want the frame to change on Scene 1

Comment: And where is the code you provided? In the main timeline, inside nav, or somewhere else?

Comment: inside the nav movieclip on the frame where my aboutbtn is

Comment: Than it'll change the frame of the `nav` movieclip. To change the frame of the main timeline, use `parent` instead of `this`, so it'll refer to `nav`s parent: the main timeline.

Comment: The code above gives me this error Symbol 'nav', Layer 'About', Frame 1, Line 3 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.